# link rel="amphtml" mandatory?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

I understand that **ideally** one should add

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```

to the non amp page
and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/url/to/standard/document.html">
```

to the amp page

However, unfortunately I don't have permissions to be able to add the link rel="amphtml" to the standard page (non amp page). Is it **mandatory** to have this for amp pages to be indexed and cached by google or does it just mean that search "credit" of the original page just wont be applied for the amp page.

What are the implications if I create my amp pages without the link from the original page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is mandatory. This is how a search engine (SE) find the AMP Version.

Duplicate Content is not a problem, the AMP version show with canonical to the original page. So why should Google Show you AMP site without the link to that?

So the implication is how can a search engine find your AMP Version, and why should is display as a alternative?

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't feel the reasoning holds up. It is possible for an AMP page to exist as standalone i.e. not have a "full site" version. in which case you set the rel canonical to point to itself. So having a link to the full version cannot be the only way SE's find AMP pages. Perhaps a better way to pose my question is, If I am unable to edit the "full" page to add the rel amphtml should I treat the AMP page as standalone and point rel canonical to itself or is it still better to point the AMP page to the full version?

Comment: I preffer cannonical to the full version. Don't forget that you become a problem with duplicate content if you have two sites with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AMP Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec), the AMP page **must** have `<link rel="canonical" href="path/to/canonical" >`. For standalone AMP the link may point to itself.
`<link rel="amphtml" href="path/to/amp" >` on a canonical page is optional. This is just how Google discovers AMP pages.
If you cannot add `rel="amphtml"` you can try

- add AMP pages to the `sitemap.xml` file,
- manually *add to index* in Google Search Console.

It may or may not work. Also note that `path/to/canonical` must be **absolute** URL.